# How to deploy Eclipse RCP app with secure properties

Tags: security, properties, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, desktop-application

I'm currently developing an Eclipse RCP e4 desktop application which will be connecting to external web based APIs. These APIs are secure and require the application to pass secure credentials to identify the application, as well as secure credentials for the user using the app. The credentials for the application will need to be deployed along with the application, what is the best way to do this securely as I obviously don't want to have them as plain text or just hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the users credentials to authenticate to the app instead of app specific credentials?

Perhaps you can use the users credentials to authenticate to another app to retrieve the app credentials?

If you want to store the user credentials locally, you can use the `ISecurePreferences` mechanism (http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/equinox/security/storage/ISecurePreferences.html).

Comment: I don't think I can do that, the app specific credentials I need encrypted are needed to let the user login to the service, so they are very app specific.

Comment: You're in a bit of a catch-22 then ... the only way to have secure credentials is to encrypt them ... and if you ship the credentials with the product, you need to ship the decryption key.  Basically you've got no security at all.

The best you can hope for in this situation is to obfuscate the decryption key.  Not optimal, but that's the only thing I can suggest.